# Do cats need clothes?

Tags: cats, safety, temperature, winter, attire

Do cats need dressing clothes when weather is cold?

If so, what is the temperature in which cats start to need clothes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cats generally have sense enough not to go outside/stay outside when it's dangerously cold unless they must. So unless you are forcing the cat outside, or your house is colder than most and you have a furless breed or *much* colder than most, this shouldn't be a problem.

Basically, most cats never need to wear clothes other than their fur. Remember, feral cats manage to survive in a wide range of climates.

Comment: I'd add that most cats simply **will not** wear clothes, and its something you'll probably only try once!

Comment: It is worth noting, however, that feral cats tend to have much shorter lifespans than pet cats, and most barn/feral cats never get to an age where they are less active and suffering from arthritis.  Elderly cats do feel the cold and may appreciate additional help to stay warm. A heated bed is usually an easier way to keep a geriatric cat warm than making him wear a sweater, however. :-D

Comment: If you have a Sphinx cat -- the hairless breed -- then a vest might make sense occasionally. Be prepared to spend a long time getting the cat used to the idea; it took me several years to convince my cats that being under blankets was warmer than nesting on top of them.

Answer (score 8):

Cats probably don't *need* a jacket or boots, since they probably don't want to stay outside in the cold for long.

But if it's cold enough where **you** would want to wear a hat & gloves outside (definitely below freezing) and *if* your cat wants to go outside, then your cat would be **a lot warmer & more comfortable** wearing a jacket or sweater. A small dog jacket would work, some have a hole for a  leash attached to a harness (worn under the jacket) to pass through too (I probably wouldn't clip a leash just to a jacket, I think cats are better at wiggling out of a jacket than dogs). And if they want to walk around in the snow or ice for a while, little boots/shoes would be a good idea too *if* they will stand wearing them (I wouldn't want to touch ice or snow for long without boots or gloves.)

Kind of like this one from [here (with instructions to make it too)](http://ohyoucraftygal.blogspot.ca/2011/12/cat-hoodie-tutorial-make-your-cat-coat.html) but not many cats like to wear hats/hoodies:

[image]

Some cats have trouble walking when they're wearing a jacket too, and especially boots, so definitely **stay with your cat** if they're wearing them, and a leash is highly recommended too.
[image]

Without a jacket on in below freezing weather a cat can get chilly pretty quickly, and start shivering and progress to more problems if they don't get somewhere warm. [This site](https://www.moveoneinc.com/blog/expat-life/enkeep-cat-warm-winter-time/) has lists a few cold weather safety tips too:

> **Cold weather problems**
>
> Sometimes owners forget that their cats are just as accustomed to the
>   warm shelter of the indoors as they are. Some owners will leave their
>   cats outside for extended periods of time, thinking that they are
>   adapted to live outdoors. This can put their pets in danger of serious
>   illness.
>
> **Hypothermia**, or a body temperature that is below normal, is a
>   condition that occurs when the cats are not able to keep their body
>   temperature from falling below normal. It happens when they spend too
>   much time in cold temperatures, or when cats with poor health or
>   circulation are exposed to cold. In mild cases, your cat will shivers
>   and show signs of depression, lethargy, and weakness. As the condition
>   progresses, her muscles will stiffen, her heart and breathing rates
>   will slow down, and she will stop responding to stimuli. If you notice
>   these symptoms, you need to get your cat warm and take her to your
>   veterinarian.
>
> Another cold-related problem is **frostbite**. Sometimes your
>   cat may accidentally be left outside or become lost during a heavy
>   snowstorm. Frostbite may result. If this happens, remember - frozen
>   tissues should never be rubbed. This causes additional tissue damage.
>   Prompt veterinary treatment is needed. If this is not possible, warm
>   the affected area rapidly by immersing in warm, never hot, water or by
>   using warm, moist towels that are changed frequently. As soon as the
>   affected tissues become flushed, discontinue warming. Gently dry the
>   affected tissues and lightly cover with a clean, dry, non-adhering
>   bandage. If frostbite is in the later stages, gangrene may set in and
>   cause all kinds of infections. So, if you suspect your cat has
>   frostbite, take her to the veterinarian.
>   [image]

Answer (score 2):

I tried a coat made from a knitted legwarmer with holes for the front paws on my cat today, because she wanted to go out in the cold.  After an hour I searched for her and she was sitting with the "coat" torn and hanging from branches.  I will never use a coat again: too dangerous.